# How to create UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code to create a view with a table programmatically

```
- (void) createView:(UIViewController*)viewController{
    _thisViewController = viewController;
    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.text = @"Title";
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 20, 200, 50);
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleLabel.font = [titleLabel.font fontWithSize: 24];

    UILabel *subtitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    subtitleLabel.text = @"Subtitle";
    subtitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 50, 400, 50);
    subtitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    subtitleLabel.font = [subtitleLabel.font fontWithSize: 20];

    UILabel *labelStatus = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    labelStatus.text = @"";
    labelStatus.frame = CGRectMake(75, screenHeight - 290, 500, 50);
    labelStatus.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    labelStatus.font = [labelStatus.font fontWithSize: 20];

    UITableView *tableDeviceList = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tableDeviceList.frame = CGRectMake(75, 100, screenWidth -250, screenHeight - 400);
    tableDeviceList.dataSource = self;
    tableDeviceList.delegate = self;

    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancelar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton sizeToFit];

    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake((screenWidth/2)-100, screenHeight - 250, 100, 50);
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x066D8B);
    cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    [cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIViewController *viewControllerModal = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIView *nooView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 80, screenWidth - 100, screenHeight - 160)];
    nooView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xE8E8E8);
    nooView.layer.cornerRadius = 20;

    [nooView addSubview:titleLabel];
    [nooView addSubview:subtitleLabel];
    [nooView addSubview:tableDeviceList];
    [nooView addSubview:labelStatus];
    [nooView addSubview:cancelButton];

    [viewControllerModal.view addSubview:nooView];

    [viewController presentViewController: viewControllerModal animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Which is throwing me an error of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, so I wonder if is there a way to add a function to a `UITableView` created this way (I'm creating my `UITableView` programmatically).

Also, my class is of type `NSObject`, so I wonder if there will be a problem with the assignment of the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of the `tableDeviceList`.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings. `tableDeviceList.dataSource = self;` probably shows a warning that self doesn't conform to the datasource protocol.  Declare the VC as conforming (see "Conforming" section here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).  That will also generate a warning that the conforming class must implement the required methods.  See @Bappaditya below for what to do next. Pay attention to warnings...many of them predict run-time crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `dataSource` and `delegate` methods of `UITableView` in your class,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1; // number of sections
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10; // should be your array count
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    cell.textlabel.text = @"test";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's also worthwhile pointing out that the numberOfRows and cellForRow should access the same datasource data, i.e. in cellForRow: `id dataForThisCell = self.theDatasourceArray[indexPath.row];` and numberOfRows says: `return self.theDatasourceArray.count`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to ios development, so I'm confused. I've read some of those methods are needed in order to use UITableView, but where is the use of datasource and delegate in that code?

Comment: @amlibtest, your view controller *becomes* the datasource by declaring that it is one, by setting the table view datasource to self, and by implementing these methods.  By doing all that, you're saying to the table view: "you do all of table stuff like scrolling and reusing cells, but I will tell you how many cells there are and how to configure them.  Just ask me via the datasource protocol"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should set the following:

```
    UITableView(your tableview name).delegate = self;
    UITableView(your tableview name).dataSource = self;
```

Secondly, you need to implement the delegate methods and datasource methods 
such as:

[image]
[image]